# ggplot2 + geom_errorbar: only plot error bars for one value, leave the 2nd w/o error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two values which I want to plot on a bar graph. One value has confidence intervals (CI) and the other doesn't. I can't figure out how to only plot the error bar fro the first value. I tried setting the upper and lower CI for the second value to second value. This indeed results in no error bar, but a slightly thicker line right on the edge of the bar in line with the width of said error bar. Is there a neater trick? Here's a little sample.

```
hleftHem <- data.frame(roi = ROIs[iRoi], names = c("control","patient"), 
                          means = c(oldBetas[iRoi,2],patBetas[iPat,iRoi]), 
                          upperCIs = c(oldBetas[iRoi,"CI+"], patBetas[iPat,iRoi]),
                          lowerCIs = c(oldBetas[iRoi,"CI-"], patBetas[iPat,iRoi]))
    p1 <- ggplot(leftHem, aes(x=names, y=means, fill=names)) + 
      geom_bar(colour="black",position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", width = .5) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) + # To use for fills, add
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lowerCIs, ymax=upperCIs), 
                    width=.15,                    # Width of the error bars
                    position=position_dodge(.9)) +
      guides(fill=FALSE) +
      theme(text = element_text(size=20),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) +  
      xlab("ROI") + ylab("Parameter estimates [a.u.]") + ggtitle(paste(roi))
```

Plotting the error bars first is not ideal, since the upper and lower CI aren't the same.

Comment: Just set the limits to `NA`.

Comment: Hey, that totally worked! Thanks!